# How to use lambda to subset a dataframe column with multiple words in the same row?

Tags: lambda, operators, subset, apply, contains

I have a dataframe with people's full names.

```
d = {'col1': ["JOHN JAMES CONNOR", "ROBERT JAMES FORBIS", "JOSEPH ROBERT SUM", "JAMES LUM ROBERT", "MARGARET ADELMAN JOHNSON", "JAMES ROBERT SMITH]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| JOHN JAMES CONNOR |
| ROBERT JAMES FORBIS |
| JOSEPH ROBERT SUM |
| JAMES LUM ROBERT |
| MARGARET ADELMAN JOHNSON |
| JAMES ROBERT SMITH |

I would like to subset it with the words ROBERT AND JAMES, regardless of the order the words are in, and find this answer.

| col1 |
| --- |
| ROBERT JAMES FORBIS |
| JAMES LUM ROBERT |
| JAMES ROBERT SMITH |

I was trying to use this:

```
d[lambda x: x['col1'].str.contains('ROBERT', na=False)] & d[lambda x: x['col1'].str.contains('JAMES', na=False)]
```

But I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is this Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

To subset a DataFrame column based on multiple words in the same row using a lambda function in Python, you can use the `apply()` method along with a lambda function that checks for the presence of each word in the row.

**This will solve above problem and give expected output:**

**code Syntax:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["JOHN JAMES CONNOR", "ROBERT JAMES FORBIS", "JOSEPH ROBERT SUM",
                                "JAMES LUM ROBERT", "MARGARET ADELMAN JOHNSON", "JAMES ROBERT SMITH"]})
    
    
    # List of words to search for
    words_to_find = {'ROBERT', 'JAMES'}
    
    # Subset the column using lambda and apply
    subset = df[df['col1'].apply(lambda row: all(word in row.split() for word in words_to_find))]
    
    print(subset)
```

Comment: This will surely solve your problem, I have tried and got correct. Hope this will help you, please upvote if this really worked for you.